# How Kaguya addresses Moeha Fujiwara

Tags: japanese-language, kaguya-sama-love-is-war

In S03E10, why does Kaguya address Moeha (Chika Fujiwara's imouto) by 1st name only after previously, in S02E02,

A - expressing reluctance to do the same for Kei (Miyuki Shirogane's imouto) and

B - addressing Moeha as Moeha-san?

Actually, afaiu, 'Moeha-san' is too polite, but I figured it was just [Kaguya's thing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67013/why-does-yor-call-anya-as-anya-san-instead-of-anya-chan) or Kaguya's school's thing (Quote: ['In that school, everybody pretty much uses keigo with everybody else'](https://youtu.be/-o9xX077SRI?t=214)).

[image]

Quote:

> This is the 1st time I've ever called someone by their 1st name only. - Kaguya about calling Kei Shirogane by 1st name.

Note 1: Kaguya [even wanted to address Kei](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67041/why-dont-anime-dubs-include-honorifics) as Shirogane-san, then Kei-san and then Kei-chan.

Note 2: Sort of cross-posted in Japanese SE: [Changing the way you address someone without your relationship having changed](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95712/changing-the-way-you-address-someone-without-your-relationship-having-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of an answer in reddit and an answer in Japanese SE:

Aestrasz from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/wgxdw8/comment/ij2q124/?context=3):

> As to why Kaguya doesn't use the "-san" in that scene, it's because she wants to convince Moeha that she's too young for the president. In Japan, you almost always call children by just their name, that's why she dropped the "-san", she was treating her like a child.

sundowner from [Japanese SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95712/changing-the-way-you-address-someone-without-your-relationship-having-changed):

> Regarding the particular case, I think your understanding (from other sites) should be fine, although it does not necessarily intimidate Moeha. It sounds like emphasizing Kaguya's status as an elder - one who instructs, educates her juniors. In a sense, it may be like using a full name in English.

My follow-up question:

> 'like using a full name in English' - ah so it's like the 'Albus Severus Potter' in Harry Potter 7? But in that case...this means the honorific change is probably temporary? Like next day things are back to normal Kaguya might go back to Moeha-san?

sundowner:

> Yes, I think it is likely to be temporary. Moeha is used just because of the nature of what Kaguya tells Moeha.