# Is Moeha the 2nd person Kaguya has addressed by 1st name only?

Tags: japanese-language, kaguya-sama-love-is-war

I ask [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/how-kaguya-addresses-moeha-fujiwara) about how in S03E10, Kaguya addresses Moeha (Chika Fujiwara's imouto) by 1st name only after previously, in S02E02,

A - expressing reluctance to do the same for Kei (Miyuki Shirogane's imouto) and

B - addressing Moeha as Moeha-san.

[image]

Quote:

> This is the 1st time I've ever called someone by their 1st name only. - Kaguya about calling Kei Shirogane by 1st name.

Question: Is Moeha the 2nd person Kaguya has addressed by 1st name only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably the on-screen case, but I think it's N/A because it's likely a temporary change based on the reasons for why Kaguya calls Moeha without the -san. See [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/how-kaguya-addresses-moeha-fujiwara) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95712/changing-the-way-you-address-someone-without-your-relationship-having-changed). Comment by sundowner:

> Yes, I think it is likely to be temporary. Moeha is used just because of the nature of what Kaguya tells Moeha.